# Can I use bindable events on gui in roblox?

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make a gui for phone users.If the player touches it, then it will run a script.My question is - Can I use Bindable Events to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using RemoteEvents since BindableEvents don't communicate between the server and the client, as said in the [official documentation for BindableEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BindableEvent).

In this case, you want a script to execute once the client interacts with the GUI. RemoteEvents are helpful in this scenario since it communicates both with the server and the client.

You could also use [RemoteFunctions](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteFunction) to have two-way communication between the client and the server if you need the result from the server to the client.